# How to stay on same page after login in php?

Tags: codeigniter

I want that even after a user presses login button he stays on the same page. My login form is located at the header and is common for all. Like suppose there are two pages home and contact. User visits home page first. Later he visits contact page. Now even if the user presses the login button in the header, whatever he might have entered in the fields doesn't matter, validation occurs and the user either logs in and stays on contact page or an error message is displayed and the user stays on the contact page. I am using codeigniter framework. Is there anything that I can use in codeigniter?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to refresh at all, or that you want to reload on the same page? If it is the first then that involves ajax and a lot of javascript...

Answer (score 5):

After authenticating the user, do a redirect header to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 2):

Hi Try to use **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** for geeting the previous url.

```
$refering_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '' ;
```

put this code in your login view page for getting the previous page url

```
$this->session->set_userdata('url', $refering_url);
```

Store that url in session,so that it can be accessed in login controllers.Get the session 
value from the conttroller and after checking login credentials ,redirect to this url

```
$url=$this->session->userdata('url');
```

For redirecting use **redirect()**

```
redirect($url, 'refresh');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

After authenticating the user you can redirect him to page of your choice

```
redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
```

You can also sent error or any messages usign for example, you will need to load session library of course.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="message">' . $error . '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`$this->agent->referrer();`

before use this you have to load library

`$this->load->library('user_agent');` in your parent class.

Answer (score 0):

$this->load->library('user_agent'); //in your parent class.
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');  //in function end redirection